# unit test failing if Log Member object (@Slf4j isn't found groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: log for class:

Tags: aspectj, slf4j, spring-aop

I'm helping my development team with some logging code in our framework.

using spring AOP I've created a groovy class called LoggingAspect.  Its main purpose is to log method execution times for classes in com.zions.comon.services.logging directories and
annotated with @Loggable.

Since some classes already have @sl4j logging I need to detect if hat log member objects exists and use the built in @slf4j logging for that class.  If it doesn't I need to execute the @sl4j annotation in aspect logging code.

The first statement in  the try block will check if log member exists on object.  If it does, then iLog will get set to incoming object's logger.  However I'm not sure how to complete the rest of the code Once I detect the log member object.  I don't expect anyone to write this code for me but would appreciate any suggestions/areas of researcoh on how to do this - such as using "if"

The logic should go something like:

1. Intercept and calculate method logging times in select classes
2. Check for existing log member object that indicates @slf4j is already present in class
3. If log member object exits use @sl4j logging features already built into that class
4. If log member object doesnt exist use @slf4j logging in logging Aspect code.

any help would be appreciated

[image: https://imgur.com/VIXAf4q.jpg] "logging flow diagram"

*Reverted code to original version - My LoggingAspect code looks like this at the moment*

```groovy
package com.zions.common.services.logging

import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy

@Aspect
@Configuration
@Slf4j
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)
public class LoggingAspect {
     * 
     * This is a Logging Aspect for the Loggable annotation that calculates method runtimes
     * for all methods under classes annotated with @Loggable*/

    /**
     * Logs execution time of method under aspect.
     * 
     * @param joinPoint - method under join
     * @return actual return of method under join point.
     * @throws Throwable
     */
    @Around('execution (* *(..)) && !execution(* *.getMetaClass()) && @within(com.zions.common.services.logging.Loggable)')
    public Object logExecutionTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

                def obj = joinPoint.this
                Logger iLog = log
                long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Object proceed = joinPoint.proceed();
                long executionTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

                try {

                    /*First statement of try block attempts to test if log members exist on object.
                     If it does, then iLog will get set to incoming object's logger*/

                    obj.log.isInfoEnabled()
                    iLog = obj.log
                } catch (e) {}

                iLog.info("${joinPoint.getSignature()} executed in ${executionTime}ms");
                return proceed;
            }
        }
```

If its helpful my logging Annotation is

```groovy
package com.zions.common.services.logging

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

/* Logging annotation to be used at class level
 * Loggable annotation for all methods of a class annotated with the @Loggable annotation*/

    @Target(ElementType.TYPE)
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface Loggable {}
```

I've added a junit test class that validates when log member is found - The line 'iLog = obj.log' get's called from the LoggingAspect code and the test is PASSING.

**LoggingAspectSpecification.groovy**

```groovy
package com.zions.common.services.logging

import static org.junit.Assert.*

import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j
import org.junit.Test
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration

import spock.lang.Specification

@ContextConfiguration(classes=[LoggingAspectSpecificationConfig])
class LoggingAspectSpecification extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    SomeClass someClass

    def 'Main flow for timing log'() {
        setup: 'class to be logged'

    when: 'execute something with class testing log'
    someClass.methodOne()
    someClass.methodTwo()

    then: 'validate something logged'
    true
    }

}


@TestConfiguration
@Profile("test")
@ComponentScan(["com.zions.common.services.logging"])
@PropertySource("classpath:test.properties")
class LoggingAspectSpecificationConfig {

    @Bean
    SomeClass someClass() {
        return new SomeClass()
    }

}

@Loggable
@Slf4j
class SomeClass {

    def methodOne() {
        log.info('run methodOne')

    }

    def methodTwo() {
        log.info('run methodTwo')
    }
}
```

However my unit test is failing with classes that do not have @Slf4j meaning it will execute with the logger of the aspect instead of the pointcut object. The full error trace is:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: log for class: com.zions.common.services.logging.SomeClass2
    at com.zions.common.services.logging.SomeClass2.methodOne(LoggingAspectSpecification2.groovy:55)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:89)
    at com.zions.common.services.logging.LoggingAspect.logExecutionTime(LoggingAspect.groovy:42)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:643)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:632)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:174)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
    at com.zions.common.services.logging.LoggingAspectSpecification2.Main flow for timing log(LoggingAspectSpecification2.groovy:27)
```

The second unit test code is below -  (the only difference is that @Slf4j) is not present in the classes.

**LoggingAspectSpecification2.groovy**

```groovy
    package com.zions.common.services.logging

    import static org.junit.Assert.*
    import groovy.util.logging.Log    
    import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j
    import org.junit.Test
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
    import org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource
    import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration

    import spock.lang.Specification

    @ContextConfiguration(classes=[LoggingAspectSpecificationConfig2])
    class LoggingAspectSpecification2 extends Specification {

        @Autowired
        SomeClass2 someClass2

        def 'Main flow for timing log'() {
            setup: 'class to be logged'

        when: 'execute something with class testing log'
        someClass2.methodOne()
        someClass2.methodTwo()

        then: 'validate something logged'
        true
        }

    }

<!-- language: lang-groovy -->

    @TestConfiguration
    @Profile("test")
    @ComponentScan(["com.zions.common.services.logging"])
    @PropertySource("classpath:test.properties")
    class LoggingAspectSpecificationConfig2 {

        @Bean
        SomeClass2 someClass2() {
            return new SomeClass2()
        }

    }

<!-- language: lang-groovy -->

    @Loggable


class SomeClass2 {
        def methodOne() {

            int  x=10, y=20;
            System.out.println(x+y+" testing the aspect logging code");

        }

        def methodTwo() {
           int  x=10, y=20;
           System.out.println(x+y+" testing the aspect logging code");
        }
    }
```

I'm guessing something's wrong in my LoggingAspect code in the Try Catch block?

Comment: I understand your description of the situation, but do not understand your problem. What is the expected result? Which result or error do you get instead? And are you using proxy-based Spring AOP or full AspectJ via load-time or compile-time weaving ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  Our framework is using AspectJ.  I'm new to programming and basically looking for any topics/areas I can research to get this done.  Should I incorporate a If Else statement in the try block when checking for log member object?  And how to code when log member object isn't found.  Of course I dont expect anyone to write the code for me -  but looking for suggestions on what topics to research

Comment: I've updated the code in my post above to show my latest changes.

Comment: Oh, why did you remove the syntax highlighting I added to your code and re-add the useless author comments I removed for you again? Now I edited your post again.

Comment: And again, you didn't answer my questions: What is the expected result? Which result or error do you get instead? Which problem do you have with the code? Your first version looked okay already, this one looks more complicated (why?) but still seems to work. There is a mistake though because in the "if" part no time is being measured but you are trying to log it. What was wrong with the old version? If you want help, please answer all questions and don't just update your code so I have to re-analyse it. I also don't see any Spring config proving you really use AspectJ and not Spring AOP.

Comment: I apologize for the incomplete post - I've updated the post to show the unit test code and an error I'm getting when log  member object (@slf4j) isn't found.  Getting the error -  groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: log for class: com.zions.common.services.logging.SomeClass2
 at com.zions.common.services.logging.SomeClass2.methodOne(LoggingAspectSpecification2.groovy:55)
 at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)

Comment: Actually you have changed back the aspect to the first version which should be alright because it catches the exception. Even the statement `obj.log.isInfoEnabled()` is not necessary because `iLog = obj.log` already performs what you think is a check for the existence of the member `log`. The `MissingPropertyException` should be silently ignored by your code. To make sure the catch block is entered, you could log the exception via `println e` or so. I suspect that your real aspect code differs from what you posted here and that you access the log member from somewhere outside of try-catch.

Comment: I was able to get both scenarios to pass by adding Log annotation to the test,                                                                                                     
_italic_@Loggable
@Log


class SomeClass2 {
 
 def methodOne() {
  
  log.info('run methodOne')
  
 }
 
 def methodTwo() {
  log.info('run methodTwo')
 }
}_italic

Comment: I don't understand your comment. This is totally unrelated to what you asked before. I just wasted my time here and I really tried to help you. You didn't answer my questions and the code you posted here definitely is not the same as the code running on your machine, as I said above. Sorry for my frustration, but this kind of (anti) communication is making me angry and disappointed because I spent my private time trying to get answers you never cared to give. :-(

Comment: i apologize for the confusion - i was having trouble editing my comment.  After adding the Log annotation to LoggingAspectSpecification2 which required importing the import groovy.util.logging.Log - the test is passing.  But this is just using the the built in java util logging for groovy and not my aspect code.  Also my LoggingAspect code is what's listed in this post.

Comment: the output from my unit test is INFO: run methodOne
07:34:44.942 [main] INFO com.zions.common.services.logging.LoggingAspect - Object com.zions.common.services.logging.SomeClass2.methodOne() executed in 5ms
Jun 16, 2019 7:34:44 AM java_util_logging_Logger$info$0 call
INFO: run methodTwo
07:34:44.981 [main] INFO com.zions.common.services.logging.LoggingAspect - Object com.zions.common.services.logging.SomeClass2.methodTwo() executed in 1ms

Comment: So is your problem solved now or not? I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the error and get my unit test to pass without @Slf4j or @Log - I had to add a println statement to the SomeClass2 code as in,

```
    int  x=10, y=20;
    System.out.println(x+y+" testing the apsect logging code");
```

adding @Log just gave it another built in log member similar to @Slf4j - adding the println statement and removing the @Log annotation force the LoggingAspect code to execute.  Unit test is passing.

Comment: That's **not the answer** to your question. The question was how to design the aspect in a way avoiding the exception you got if the target class does **not** have that annotation. I suggest you just delete the whole question because the answer helps no-one and the whole communication with you was just a mess. You have never been able to even explain what the problem was because I used your approach and it works on my workstation.